# Formatting the jquery slider tool tip text

Tags: jquery, d3.js

How can i format the jquery slider tooltip text to percentage  (10-100%)?As im using d3 js. Thats is zoom.scaleExtent([0.2, 2]).

```
var tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 20
        }).hide();

        $(".slider").slider({
            animate: "slow",
            range: "min",
            orientation: "vertical",
            min: zoom.scaleExtent()[0],
            max: zoom.scaleExtent()[1],
            value: scaleZ ,
            step: ((zoom.scaleExtent()[1] - zoom.scaleExtent()[0]) / 100),
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                tooltip.text(ui.value);
                slideFn(ui.value);
            }
        }).find(".ui-slider-handle").append(tooltip).hover(function() {
            tooltip.show()
        }, function() {
            tooltip.hide()
        });
```

When i slide I'm getting the values from 0.2 to 2 in the tooltip but i need it from 10% to 100%.  [jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/205](http://%20jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/205)

Comment: JSFiddle pleast fekky :))

Comment: HI AJ http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/aVhd8/205/    please check this

Comment: Also when i zoomIn and zoomOut its doesn't  zoom from center. But when i use mouse wheel it zoom from center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/aVhd8/206/

**JS:-**

```
 slide: function(event, ui) {
                    tooltip.text(ui.value*100+"%");
                    slideFn(ui.value);
                }
```

Comment: Yes, but  max value seems 99.00 Is it possible to make 100%

Comment: @fekkyDEV Does this answer your question??